# How to load a marker png from within leaflet that is held in assets/images of a production site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, leaflet, asset-pipeline

My rails site is using the leaflet gem.  I have no trouble loading the png in development, but when I switch to my production site the path now start under leaflet.

I want my path to by MY_WEB_SITE/assets/images/ but in production it becomes MY_WEB_SITE/assets/leaflet/dist/images/

I've attached .erb to my coffeescript. And the following code:

```
digested_icon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-icon.png' %>"
  iconRetinaUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-icon-2x.png' %>"
  shadowUrl: "<%= asset_path 'marker-shadow.png' %>"
})
sgMarker = L.marker(sgLatLng, {icon: digested_icon})
```

I've also tried asset_url, but it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Configure asset pipeline to compile .png files (particularly in vendor/ as it's not done by default):

```
# In config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["*.png"]
```

This will allow your .png images to be compiled to public/assets/leaflet/dist/images/ then they will show up in production.